# Xamarin pan gesture recognizer not giving accurate coordinates

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm doing some testing with a pan gesture recognizer.  The setup is pretty simple, I have a box view that is 20x20 and is being set by a relative layout.  The handler for the pan gesture

```
switch (args.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Running:
                    box.TranslationX = box.X + args.TotalX;
                    box.TranslationY = box.Y + args.TotalY;
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    box.TranslationX = 0;
                    box.TranslationY = 0;
                    break;
            }
```

So it runs ok, but when I try dragging the boxview around the screen, it doesn't translate the values properly.  It also gives this really nasty flashing effect as it tries to redraw the box.  Is there a better way to go about doing this?  Is there a way to get rid of the flashing?

Comment: what layout are you using?

Comment: It is in a relative layout.

Comment: I've implemented the example provided by Xamarin ([Adding a Pan Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pan/)) and the same behavior occurs. The element I try to move is flashing during the gesture (in reality it is switching really quick from one position to another, that causes this "flashing" effect).

Answer (score 5):

Well, if it is your box which have the PanGestureRecognizer, the flashing effect is simply because TotalX and TotalY are relative to box **translation** coordinates.

Try changing

```
box.TranslationX = box.X + args.TotalX;
box.TranslationY = box.Y + args.TotalY;
```

by

```
box.TranslationX = box.TranslationX + args.TotalX;
box.TranslationY = box.TranslationY + args.TotalY;
```

It should work.

edit: it only concerns Xamarin Android, it work differently for UWP.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on **Julien's** solution which solved the issue for me (on Android)...

The Pan Gesture coordinates, contained in the **PanUpdatedEventArgs**, can be intercepted and recalculated to counter for the movement of the BoxView itself. Then pass the new **Args** on to another handler:

```
    public void Handle_PanUpdated(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        double TranslationX = box.TranslationX;
        double TranslationY = box.TranslationY;

        double TotalX_Modified = e.TotalX + TranslationX;
        double TotalY_Modified = e.TotalY + TranslationY;

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        { 
            e = new PanUpdatedEventArgs(e.StatusType, e.GestureId, TotalX_Modified, TotalY_Modified);
        }

        Handle_PanUpdate_Modified(sender, e);
    }
```

Comment: This fixed my problem on MAUI when using TranslateTo().

Answer (score 1):

I found an implementation on Xamarin Forums that can help you to fix your problem ([Pinch and Pan gesture recognizers not working on Android project](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60374/pinch-and-pan-gesture-recognizers-not-working-on-android-project)). Here is the Pan implementation, I tested it with my project and noticed that the "flashing" effect is no more present:

```
private double startScale, currentScale, xOffset, yOffset, startX, startY;
...
public void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.StatusType)
    {
        case GestureStatus.Started:
            startX = e.TotalX;
            startY = e.TotalY;
            Content.AnchorX = 0;
            Content.AnchorY = 0;
            break;

        case GestureStatus.Running:
            var maxTranslationX = Content.Scale * Content.Width - Content.Width;
            Content.TranslationX = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(-maxTranslationX, xOffset + e.TotalX - startX));

            var maxTranslationY = Content.Scale * Content.Height - Content.Height;
            Content.TranslationY = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(-maxTranslationY, yOffset + e.TotalY - startY));
            break;

        case GestureStatus.Completed:
            xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
            yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
            break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm working through it now, however the maxTranslation is always coming back as 0.  It looks like it should be something like var maxTranslationX = Content.Scale * Screen.Width - Content.Width?  Where you use the screen width and not the content width?  Or am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally done it, 
Assume I want to drag a boxview over the screen without any flashing or coordination accuracy issue, 
I created a container for the view that I want to drag over the screen, Created a 
DragEnd event and specific EventArgs on it and when this event raised in the main form I deleted this container from layout's children list and re added new one with data that carried by EventArgs :

PanContainer.cs :

```
public class PanContainer : ContentView
{
    public delegate void DragEndEventHandler(object sender, DragEventArgs e);

    public PanContainer()
    {
        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
    }

    public event DragEndEventHandler DragEnd;

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                Content.TranslationX = e.TotalX;
                Content.TranslationY = e.TotalY;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                OnDragEnd(new DragEventArgs(Content.TranslationX, Content.TranslationY, Width, Height, X, Y));
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Canceled:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDragEnd(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DragEnd?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}

public class DragEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DragEventArgs(double translationX, double translationY, double w, double h, double x, double y)
    {
        ContentTranslationX = translationX;
        ContentTranslationY = translationY;
        Width = w;
        Height = h;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public double ContentTranslationX { get; set; }
    public double ContentTranslationY { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

and in the Main form :

```
    private void DraggableOnDragEnd(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var bv = new BoxView
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Brown
        };
        var pc = new PanContainer
        {
            Padding = 4,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Chartreuse,
            Content = bv
        };
        absoluteLayout.Children.Add(pc,
            new Rectangle(e.X + e.ContentTranslationX, e.Y + e.ContentTranslationY, e.Width, e.Height));
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                absoluteLayout.Children.Remove(
                    absoluteLayout.Children.First(x => x.GetType() == typeof(PanContainer)));
                var v = absoluteLayout.Children.First(x => x.GetType() == typeof(PanContainer));
                ((PanContainer) v).DragEnd += DraggableOnDragEnd;
            });
        });
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teU0v.gif)

It works correctly but maybe there is better way to do it ..